# How to use a Butterworth bandpass filter to generate a chirped signal

Tags: signal-processing

As there is no `ChirpSignal` function in *Mathematica*, I wrote a simple code to generate a  sinusoid with a frequency that changes continuously from frequency `f1` to `f2` over a certain time of `t`

This is what I"ve done to generate the chirp:

```
{freq0, freqs, TrBandw, RCbandw, pulseLength, dt} = 
  {9 10^6, {10 10^6, 20 10^6}, 4, 10^6, 5 10^5, 2.67 10^-6, 1 10^-8};

i = 0;
nfreqs = Length@freqs;
n = Ceiling[pulseLength/dt];

fmin = freqs[[1]] - RCbandw/2;
fmax = freqs[[-1]] + RCbandw/2;

nextend = n*nfreqs;
w = 2 Pi (fmin + Range[0, nextend - 1] (fmax - fmin)/(nextend - 1));

Phi = 
  PadRight[
    Accumulate[Insert[Table[w[[i]] dt, {i, 2, n*nfreqs}], 0, 1]], 
    IntegerPart[((nfreqs + 1) pulseLength)/dt], 
    0];

s = Sin[Phi];
```

[image]

**Through my previous question I learned simpler methods to generate a chirp, BUT I still need to filter the chirp with a Butterworth to remove frequencies that do not fit in the span of [cut1, cut2]**

```
cut1 = (freq0 - 0.5 TrBandw)/(1/dt/2)
cut2 = (freq0 + 0.5 TrBandw)/(1/dt/2)

cut1 = 0.14 Hz
cut2 = 0.22 Hz
```

I know how to filter the signal in matlab and the final result looks something like this

[image]

**However, my entire code is written in Mathematica, so it would be great to have help with the filtering part, too.**

Comment: None of the answers address the Butterworth bandpass filter which completes the process of generating the chirped signal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear[PulseTemplateChirp];
PulseTemplateChirp[freq0_, freqs_, TrBandw_, RCbandw_, pulseLength_, 
  dt_] :=
 Block[{fmin, fmax, chirpLength0, nfreqs, 
   chirpLength, \[Phi],(*chirp0,*)cut1, cut2, tf, dtf, chirp1, cut01, 
   cut02, bwf, dbwf, chirpn, z},

  fmin = freqs[[1]] - RCbandw/2;
  fmax = freqs[[-1]] + RCbandw/2;

  chirpLength0 = Round[pulseLength/dt] + 1;
  nfreqs = Length@freqs;
  chirpLength = nfreqs chirpLength0;

  \[Phi] = PadRight[
    Accumulate[
     Insert[
      Table[
       2 \[Pi] (fmin + (fmax - fmin)/chirpLength t) dt, {t, 2, 
        chirpLength}]
      , 0, 1]
     ],
    IntegerPart[((nfreqs + 1) pulseLength)/dt], 0];

  chirp0 = Sin[\[Phi]];


  cut1 = (freq0 - 0.5 TrBandw)/0.5;
  cut2 = (freq0 + 0.5 TrBandw)/0.5;

  (*This creates a Butterworth filter with a 5 dB passband at 
  cut1\[LessEqual]f\[LessEqual]cut2 and -50 dB stopbands at f\
\[LessEqual](0.8cut1) and f\[GreaterEqual](2cut2)*)
  tf = ButterworthFilterModel[{"Bandpass", 
     2 \[Pi] {0.8 cut1, cut1, cut2, 2 cut2}, {50., 5.}}];
  (*Convert to discrete-time IIR filter*)
  dtf = ToDiscreteTimeModel[tf, 0.5 dt, z];
  (*Filter chirp sequence*)
  chirp1 = RecurrenceFilter[dtf, chirp0];

  chirpn =
   Reap[
     Do[
      cut01 = (freqs[[i]] - 0.5 RCbandw)/0.5;
      cut02 = (freqs[[i]] + 0.5 RCbandw)/0.5;

      bwf = 
       ButterworthFilterModel[{"Bandpass", 
         2 \[Pi] {0.9 cut01, cut01, cut02, 2 cut02}, {15., 2.}}];
      dbwf = ToDiscreteTimeModel[bwf, 0.5 dt, z];

      Sow[RecurrenceFilter[dbwf, chirp1]],

      {i, nfreqs}]
     ][[2, 1]]
  ]


chirps = PulseTemplateChirp[9 10^6, {10 10^6, 12 10^6}, 4 10^6,5 10^5, 2.67 10^-6, 1 10^-8];

ListLinePlot[chirps[[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your answer to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63685/how-to-generate-a-chirped-signal - is there a specific reason to post it here as well?